# Flutter barcode scanner on for web in IOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, barcode-scanner

I want to scan barcode **(not QR Code)** in flutter web specially in IOS chrome or safari.
but I can't find any suitable library for this.

mobile_scanner: ^2.0.0
simple_barcode_scanner: ^0.0.5
flutter_barcode_sdk: ^2.1.2
barcode_reader_webassembly: ^0.0.5
ai_barcode: ^3.2.4

I already test this library but most of them just scan QR code in web not barcode and need barcode scanner

is there any library for this goal?
am I miss something when using above libraries?
is this possible to scan barcode in web?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner  This plugin scan both QR and Barcode in the mobile devices

Comment: @KKMuhammedFazil I want to scan in flutter web not IOS. this library don't support web –

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080519/flutter-barcode-scanner-on-mobile-web-app ?

Answer (score -1):

Found one that is not in your list, and supports iOS:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner

Comment: I want to scan in flutter web not IOS. this library don't support web